# System.Byte[] can not be assigned to a property of type System.String setter

Tags: mysql, nhibernate

Hi i could not find the correct section to post this. But i am facing a serious problem working with MySQL and Nhibernate 2.1.2.4.0 named queries. 
I have written a stored procedure and i am calling it in C# using a flat class to map the database fields. My problem is it seems to work fine with Mysql 5.1 but not with 5.0

I have a STRING property day_of_week in my class. But when i try to call  the stored procedure it throws the following error :

> **The type System.Byte[] can not be assigned to a property of type System.String setter of "AssessmentFeedbackReportDTO.DayOfTheWeek" .**

It works without any fuss in MySql v 5.1

Any help is much appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: For a problem like this, it'd help to see your class and mappings, along with the relevant database info.  The version of MySql.Data that you're using would help also.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the stored procedure to convert charset to utf8 or other encoding -
SELECT CONVERT(column USING utf8) FROM...